# How to check if Intel Virtualization is enabled without going to BIOS in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, x86-64, intel, virtualization

I want to check if Intel virtualization is enabled in my laptop or not (Lenovo Thinkpad, Win 10 64 bit). Is there any way available to check it without going to BIOS?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Right-click Start > Run > *msinfo32*

The first page shows whether virtualization is enabled in BIOS (firmware).

[image: msinfo32 "Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware Yes"]

**Alternate Method**
In PowerShell run:
`Get-ComputerInfo -property "HyperV*"`

```
PS C:\temp> Get-ComputerInfo -property "HyperV*"

HyperVisorPresent                                 : True
HyperVRequirementDataExecutionPreventionAvailable : True
HyperVRequirementSecondLevelAddressTranslation    : True
HyperVRequirementVirtualizationFirmwareEnabled    : True
HyperVRequirementVMMonitorModeExtensions          : True
```

The line `HyperVRequirementVirtualizationFirmwareEnabled    : True` shows if virtualization is enabled in BIOS (firmware).

Comment: What if only the first `HyperVisorPresent` is `True` and others are empty?

Comment: It could be that either the PowerShell version is less than 5.1 (run msinfo32 instead) or Windows Edition is not Pro, Enterprise, or Education. Reference https://thinkpowershell.com/powershell-set-up-hyper-v-lab/

Comment: in my case, both are true: it's Win 10 Pro and PS 5.1, but `Get-ComputerInfo -property "HyperV*"` shows what GooDeeJAY described

Comment: Perhaps the [Hardware Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-requirements#hardware-requirements) are not met: 64-bit CPU with SLAT, CPU support for VM MME /VT-x, 4 GB memory.      
Or is VT-x / VM Monitor Mode Extensions disabled in BIOS settings? Or Hardware Enforced Data Execution Prevention in BIOS settings?

Comment: @mrDev it is explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/kernel-dma-protection-for-thunderbolt#using-system-information

Comment: Yeah my HyperVisorPresent is True, all the rest are empty...

This is a 'sudden' change in my Homestead... it used to work perfectly fine...

I remember toggling something on (Security setting) in windows before it all went the wrong way... I remember it might have been some security regarding speaking with external computers, ofcourse I cant find that setting now.

Answer (score 124):

**First method – Easiest option- Check your Task Manager**

If you have Windows 10 or Windows 8 operating system, the easiest way to check is by opening up Task Manager->Performance Tab. You should see Virtualization as shown in the below screenshot. If it is enabled, it means that your CPU supports Virtualization and is currently enabled in BIOS. If it shows disabled, you need to enable it in BIOS. If you don’t see virtualization, it means that your CPU does not support virtualization. Read [here](https://www.shaileshjha.com/how-to-find-out-if-intel-vt-x-or-amd-v-virtualization-technology-is-supported-in-windows-10-windows-8-windows-vista-or-windows-7-machine/) for more information.
[image]

Comment: I've observed at least one case where Task Manager has shown "Virtualization: Enabled" despite the fact that I had `VT-d` explicitly disabled in BIOS so I'm not entirely certain how representative this feature is.

Comment: My Task Manager doesn't have a line showing "Virtualization" at all, even though it's enabled.

Comment: Is it "VT-d" or "VT-x"?

Comment: This also works for Windows 11